# User model with validation, delegates, and carrierwave upload mounter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I've refactored this model about 50 times according to codeclimate, trying to get the code smell down. With all of the associations, I feel like this is as bare bones as I can get it while still keeping the necessary associations. I wanted to throw it up on here and see what people thought or if anyone had any suggestions on what I could do differently. It's pretty basic, has some custom validators for email and passwords, delegates, carrierwave upload mounter and some concerns included.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "users_standard"

  include Scopeable::Clientable, Searchable, Auditable
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  belongs_to :role
  has_many :discussion_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passtokens
  has_many :attendees
  has_many :authorized_ipads
  has_many :bookjobs
  with_options foreign_key: "user_id" do |user|
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :questions,    join_table: "questions_users"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :chatposts,    join_table: "chatusers"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions,  join_table: "permissions_users"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :committees,   join_table: "committees_users"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :bookfolders,  join_table: "bookfolders_users"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :efolders,     join_table: "efolders_users"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :surveys,      join_table: "surveys_users"
    user.has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks,        join_table: "tasks_users"
  end

  with_options uniqueness: { scope: :client_id } do |user| 
    user.validates :email, email: true, allow_blank: true
    user.validates :companyemail, email: true, allow_blank: true
    user.validates :login, presence: true
  end
  validates :firstname, :lastname, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: { message: "does not match" }, password: true, allow_blank: true

  before_save do |u|
    if u.password.present?
      self.password_hash = SecurePasswordService.new(self.password).secure
      self.p2            = true
    end
  end

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions, allow_destroy: true

  delegate :title, :hostname, :forge_email_sender, :email_from, :email_new_account, :profile_update_email, :remove_email_footer, :disclaimer, :disclaimer_expiration_period, :password_change_days, :ftlogin, :user_lockout, to: :client, prefix: true

  mount_uploader :photo, UserPhotoUploader

  def self.active
    where('active = 1 and (system = 0 or system is null) and global_spawn != 1').order('lastname asc')
  end

  def self.private_directory_list(user)
    joins(:committees).where('committees.id in (?)', user.committees.map(&:id))
  end

  def endpoint_safe
    { user: self.attributes.with_indifferent_access.except!(:client_id) }
  end

  def is_committee_member?(committee)
    (committee.is_a?(Committee) && self.committees.include?(committee)) or (!committee.is_a?(Committee) && committee.map{ |c| self.committees.include?(c) })
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A partial (an really short) answer:

for `User.active` method you have the following:

`system = 0 or system is null`

I think you should change the condition order to

`system is null or system = 0`

This because when (and depending of dbms) the database compare `null` with a value (`system = 0` could be `null = 0`) it can invalidate the condition.